# How to redirect sub.example.com to www.example.com with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, apache2

I would like to redirect sub.example.com to www.example.com. I used the Rewrite of .htaccess. I wrote this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example.+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I already activate the rewrite with: sudo a2enmod rewrite.

And I already rewrite example.com to www.example.com with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Do you know how I have to write my Rewrite rules in this case?

Comment: What exactly is wrong? These rules should be fine as is to do what you want. The only possible issue I see is that `RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]` won't have a capture group and should be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: When I did "curl -I http://sub.example.com", the URL is not redirect to www.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the domain name, you can use one rule for both cases:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(sub\.)?example.+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.exemple.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```